# Qual a forma correta de chamar função dentro de outra função aninhada?

Tags: javascript

Por exemplo:

```
function principal()
{    function one_level_1(){...}
     one_level_1();
     function two_level_1(){...}
     two_level_1();
     function three_level_1()
     {    function one_level_2(){...}
          one_level_2();
     }
     three_level_1();
}

<input type="text" onfocus="one_level_2();"/>
```

Gostaria que no evento `onfocus` desse `input` chamasse a funcão `one_level_2` de modo que apenas as instruções internas a ela fossem executadas.

Qual a forma correta de chamar essa função?

Tentei `<input type="text" onfocus="(principal().three_level_1().one_level_2();)"/>`, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Este exemplo que você deu não esta muito claro para mim. Por que você auto executa a função logo apos declará-la? estas funções usam/alteram variáveis do escopo mais externo?

Answer (score 1):

Acho que é isso que você precisa.

```js
function principal() {

  function one_level_1(){
    console.log('one level 1');
  }
  
  principal.one_level_1 = one_level_1;
    
  function two_level_1(){
    console.log('two level 1');
  }
  
  principal.two_level_1 = two_level_1;
     
  function three_level_1(){    
    function one_level_2(){      
      console.log('three_level_1 -> one level 2');
    }
            
    three_level_1.one_level_2 = one_level_2;
  }
  
  principal.three_level_1 = three_level_1;
}

principal();
principal.three_level_1();
```

```html
<input type="text" onfocus="principal.three_level_1.one_level_2()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As funções declaradas dessa forma não são possiveis de serem chamos por `onfocus`, apenas pela função `principal`.

Para que realiza essa chamada, precisa extrair a função para fora mesmo.

Pois a forma que a função foi declarado, somente é executado, não consegue formar uma hierarquia

```
function principal()
{    function one_level_1(){...}
     one_level_1();
     function two_level_1(){...}
     two_level_1();
     function three_level_1()
     {    
          one_level_2();
     }
     three_level_1();
}
function one_level_2(){...}

<input type="text" onfocus="one_level_2();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você só precisa tirar as declarações das funções de dentro do escopo da função `principal`, fazendo isso, elas estarão acessíveis globalmente e não apenas no escopo da função `principal`.

```
function principal() {
  one_level_1();

  two_level_1();

  three_level_1();
}

function one_level_1() { ... }

function two_level_1() { ... }

function three_level_1() {
  one_level_2();
}

function one_level_2() { ... }

<input type = "text" onfocus = "one_level_2();" / >
```

### Veja abaixo um exemplo funcional:

```js
function principal() {
  console.log('Função principal');
  nivel1();

  function escopoPrincipal() {
    console.log('Função acessível apenas no escopo principal');
  }
  escopoPrincipal();
}

function nivel1() {
  console.log('Função nível 1');
  nivel1_2();
}

function nivel1_2() {
  console.log('Função nível 2');
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="console.clear();principal()">Função principal</a><br />
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="console.clear();nivel1()">Função nível 1</a><br />
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="console.clear();nivel1_2()">Função nível 1 2</a><br />
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="console.clear();escopoPrincipal()">Função do escopo da função principal - não acessível globalmente</a>
```